# Unsure of Return Type For My Service Implementation

Tags: architecture, asp.net-core-2.1

I have a layered core 2.1 web API solution that has 5 projects. Data is for my repositories using the repository pattern. Helpers have my Utility classes. Models are my models. The Service layer houses the code to connect to the repositories. WebAPI is the front with controllers with Restful attribute routing. The controller calls into the service layer which calls into the repos for data using the helpers and models.

This is a re-write and I am in the process of moving the controller code to the service layer which have interfaces. Most of the method signatures have a Task and as I move them back I am not sure how to return the data because when it was in the controller it had a return Content(result).

Controller logic:
`public async Task<IActionResult> ResourceLoginByUserName([FromBody] ResourceLogin obj)`

Interface for Service layer:
`Task<IActionResult> ResourceLoginByUserName(ResourceLogin obj, HttpRequest Request, string connectionString);`

Service layer code:
`public Task<string> ResourceLoginByUserName(ResourceLogin obj, HttpRequest Request, string connectionString)`
{
    `//This works as a return type of Task<string> but not IActionResult`
    return Task.FromResult();
}

`If I put IActionresult on the Service layer signature I get the error: Cannot implicitly convert type System.Threading.Tasks.Task<string> to System.Threading.Tasks.Task<Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.IActionResult>.`

I just need to know the correct pattern for doing it please? TIA

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The type for the generic type param of `Task<T>` should be simply the type of the object the method should return. I'm not exactly sure what the confusion is. You haven't really provided any information for what kind of types you're working with, but in the case of something like `ResourceLoginByUserName`, you likely want to return some sort of object with a success/fail status, an access token, and a list of errors if there were any. For example:

```
public class LoginResult
{
    public bool Succeeded { get; set; }
    public string AccessToken { get; set; }
    public List<string> Errors { get; set; } = new List<string>();
}
```

In which case the return would be `Task<LoginResult>`.

Basically, you just need to build a class that models the information you think you might need from the method call, and then return that. In a situation where you're fetching something, you can either return the object directly:

```
public Task<Foo> GetFoo(int id)
```

Or you still may want to create a specialized result class to provide additional information:

```
public class GetFooResult
{
    public bool Succeeded { get; set; }
    public Foo Foo { get; set; }
    public List<string> Errors { get; set; }
}
```

It's entirely up to you and what you need in your application. I will say it's better to follow a pattern for ease. For example, you can always return some sort of "result" class, and then you would know that you can always check `result.Succeeded` for a general pass/fail conditional.

Comment: So the service layer method will return a string...could be data or an error like ex.Message...so it would seem that returning the Task<string> is correct on the method and the interface...just been a while since I have worked with this stuff. My solution builds without errors but I just wanted to check with someone.

Comment: If you need multiple return types, that's when a result object comes into play. With that you can return your string and errors in case there's an issue getting the string. Preferable to throwing exceptions as that slows down your app.